# CKEditor 5 with Nuxt 3 - "Component is missing template or render function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I've installed the dependencies:

```
npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue
```

Then, implemented it in component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="w-full h-[400px]">
    <CKEditor
        v-model="text"
        :editor="ClassicEditor"
        :config="config"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Component setup:

```js
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";
const config = {
    toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
    heading: {
        options: [
            { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
            { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
            { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
        ]
    }
}
const text = ref('')
```

Component included it root component:

```html
          <client-only>
            <InputWysiwyg/>
            </client-only>
```

And when i am opening page with wysiwyg, i am receiving warning:  Component is missing template or render function. at CKEditor element. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if someone will search for this, i would suggest just create CKEditor instance by yourself:

```js
const editor = ref(null)
const ck = ref(null)
const init = () => {
    ck.value = ClassicEditor.create(editor.value)
}
onMounted(() => {
    init()
})
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="w-full h-[400px]">
        <div class="w-full h-full" ref="editor"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```